# Excel: Highlighting a whole column depending on date

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have made my own Gantt chart in Excel, which is shown in this picture:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ECNEAOW.png].

I would like to highlight the whole column (or until the last activity) depending on the date, as shown in the picture. I figured out how to highlight a single cell depending on the date, but not a whole column.

I don't know how to do it short of entering the date into the whole column, but I thought there would be something more efficient if conditional formatting is used.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you'd like an entire range to `conditionally format` based on the value of one of the fields in the range, use an absolute cell reference. I couldn't figure out perfectly from your picture which cell contains the date, but I'll try to give you an example.

If you have dates in the Cells in `Row 1`, and you want to highlight the entire column when the row has today's date, the conditional format formula would look like below. (Assuming today's date is in cell C1, then the entire column from C1:C25 [the range upon which I applied the conditional format] will be highlighted).

Steps:

1. Highlight the entire range upon which you want to apply the formatting. In my example, I'm using range `A1:H25`
2. In the Excel Ribbon, select Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule...
3. On Windows, select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. On macOS, first choose `Classic` from the Style dropdown menu and then from the second dropdown menu, pick `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.
4. The formula will be `=A$1=TODAY()` [NOTE: We check cell `A1` first because it is the first cell in our highlighted range. We choose `$1` because the dates are always in Row 1. Change that to suit.]
5. Select the format you'd like to apply
6. To test out how it looks, press OK

Comment: I'm amazed at how fast you responded, thanks a lot! I got it to work, I edited the formula slightly to work for my sheet, but it worked like a charm.

My dates were on the second row, and I started my highlighting in the C column. Therefore my formula is =C$2=TODAY().

Comment: No problem. If it worked, mark the question as `answered` to assist future users who are searching with a similar problem.